# MS-SQL: SQL "group" creates duplicates?

Tags: sql, group-by

when i do a count on rows (code #1) - i get the correct count of around 880 rows.

when i group the count, by date - it suddenly grows by around 100 (code #2).

i'd appreciate it if someone could help me understand my issue!

thanks in advance!

here is the table structure:

```
tblApplicants:

applicantID (index)   |     ApplyingForYear (nvarchar) 
------------------------------------------------------
1                           2013/14
11                          2013/14
13                          2013/14
12                          2013/14
15                          2013/14
21                          2012/13


tblApplicantSchools_shadow: 

id (index)   |    applicantID    |    updated (datetime)   |   statusID (int)   |   schoolID (int)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   11                  2012-09-24 00:00:00.000     3                   2
1                   13                  2012-10-24 00:00:00.000     4                   2
2                   15                  2012-11-24 00:00:00.000     3                   4
3                   13                  2012-03-24 00:00:00.000     4                   3
4                   12                  2012-09-24 00:00:00.000     4                   1
5                   21                  2012-11-03 00:00:00.000     5                   2
6                   11                  2012-09-04 00:00:00.000     4                   4
```

code #1 (counts correctly):

```
select count(DISTINCT [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].applicantID) as TotalAppsPerWeek FROM tblApplicants  
INNER JOIN tblApplicantSchools_shadow ON tblApplicantS.ApplicantID =   tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID
WHERE ApplyingForYear = '2013/14' and [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].statusID = 4
```

code #2 (group, counts incorrectly):

```
select DATEADD(ww,(DATEDIFF(ww,0,[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)),0) AS Datesubmitted ,count(DISTINCT [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].applicantID) as TotalAppsPerWeek FROM tblApplicants  
INNER JOIN tblApplicantSchools_shadow ON tblApplicantS.ApplicantID =   tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID
WHERE ApplyingForYear = '2013/14' and [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].statusID = 4
group by DATEADD(ww,(DATEDIFF(ww,0,[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)),0)
order by DATEADD(ww,(DATEDIFF(ww,0,[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)),0)
```

Desired Result:

```
    Datesubmitted              TotalAppsPerWeek
    -------------------------------------------------------
    2011-11-14 00:00:00.000    1
    2012-09-24 00:00:00.000    1
    2012-10-08 00:00:00.000    3
    2012-10-22 00:00:00.000    2
    2012-10-29 00:00:00.000    2
    2012-11-05 00:00:00.000    2
    2012-11-12 00:00:00.000    5
    2012-11-19 00:00:00.000   26
    2012-11-26 00:00:00.000   106
    2012-12-03 00:00:00.000   353
    2012-12-10 00:00:00.000   298
```

**FIDDLE CODE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/10**

Answer (score 1):

you are using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` which both do the same thing. you should use one of them

if you want use `GROUP BY`

then try this

```
   GROUP BY tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID
```

in your first query its already grouped by `tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID` so i dont know why you group again in the second query

EDIT:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that you can use nonaggregated columns or calculations in the SELECT list that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. For example, you do not need to group on tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID in the following query

```
In standard SQL, you would have to add tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID to the GROUP BY clause. In MySQL, the name is redundant.
```

Comment: thanks. the distinct i need because there could be a few entries of the same `applicantID` with `statusID = 4` - and i only want one of them - per applicantID

Comment: then why you need second group by ?

Comment: you are right - this was partial code i threw together. i am grouping so that i can see how many applicants i got - on a certain day. such that i am doing the count + the date, here is the actual code: 
`select  DATEADD(ww,(DATEDIFF(ww,0,[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)),0) AS Datesubmitted ,count(DISTINCT [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].applicantID)  as TotalAppsPerWeek       `

Comment: can you give some sample data with your wished result ?

Comment: please update your question , and add some sample data of your tables and the wished result.

Comment: what you mean by this value `ww` ? is it a special value or string or what ?

Comment: in your example above whats the value of `ww` ?

Comment: ww is the a parameter of the date functions - for "week" - it rounds the date to the closest sunday of that week. in this way - i get my results grouped by week.

Comment: there is no `DATEADD` function do you mean `ADDDATE` or `DATE_ADD`

Comment: there is something wrong with the parameter of your `datediff` can you fix it here ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/372e4/20

Comment: ok, i feel silly. i forgot to point out this is for MS-SQL

Comment: updated schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/10

Comment: here is your result with your last query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/9 . how you want will be ?

Comment: perfect. note - there are 4 rows in the result.  but if you remove the "group by" and the date field (as in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/18) you will get 3 rows. how come?

Comment: i think you look for this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/20 it returns 4

Comment: but it should be 3 - because the applicantID of "13" appears twice. thats why i need both COUNT and DISTINCT

Comment: your dates are different in `DATESUBMITTED` thats why they are 4 if you group by them. and your distinct play no role here if you remove it.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/23

Comment: i'm sorry. i dont understand.  if we look at the data in `tblApplicantSchools_shadow` - there are 4 entries that have a `statusID` of 4. but `applicantID` of `13` appears twice. therefore the correct result should be 3. out of those 3 results - i want to group them by date (weekly).  so the question is how to get to this result.  thanks!

Comment: edited my answer. its seems in mysql there is this feature to group by column which is not function aggregate. but in mssql you must group by function aggregate even if it will give you other results. in mysql it works good this feature

Comment: i see your edit - what does `customer.name` mean?

Comment: sorry it was mistake i edited it.

Comment: thank you - tried that, but no go. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/40

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because `distinct` in the second query applies to a group, so `tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID`, that have distinct `[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated` collapse in the first query and count as one, but in the second query they don't, because they are in different groups.